# Using Aggregation in WebFlux

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I 'm using WebFlux to load data from mongoDB database , my problem is how can I make an aggregation for many collections in this case "countries","airports" using repositories ?

```
package com.example.demo.web;

import com.example.demo.domain.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CountryController {

    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;
    private final AirportRepository airportRepository;
    private final RunwayRepository runwayRepository;

    public CountryController(CountryRepository countryRepository, AirportRepository airportRepository, RunwayRepository runwayRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
        this.airportRepository = airportRepository;
        this.runwayRepository = runwayRepository;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("/request")
    public Flux<Country> getAll(@RequestParam String name){
        Flux<Country> countries = this.countryRepository.findAllByNameIsStartingWith(name);
        countries.map(country ->
        {
            List<Airport> airportList = new ArrayList<Airport>();
            Airport airport =  new  Airport();
            airport.setIsoCountry(country.code);
            country.setAirports(airportList);
            return country;
        });
        return countries;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you ask about data aggregation only you can try this:

```
public Flux<Country> getAll(@RequestParam String name) {
    return countryRepository.findAllByNameIsStartingWith(name)
            .flatMap(country ->
                    airportRepository.findAllByCountryId(country.getId())
                            .map(addAirportToCountry(country))
                            .reduce((country1, country2) -> country2) // it is the same country
            );
}

private Function<Airport, Country> addAirportToCountry(Country country) {
    return airport -> {
        country.addAirport(airport);
        return country;
    };
}
```

Here we:

- make a request for countries,
- for each country make request for it's airports
- reduce the airports Flux to group it by countries

But in case of NoSQL DB it would be better to use denormalized DB schema. 
In such case the Country entity should contain the list of related Airports. So the request:

```
countryRepository.findAllByNameIsStartingWith(name);
```

would return all you need.

Comment: But I need to understand why we don't can make a simple aggregation mongodb in bean of Spring and add it as function in Repository interface ?

Comment: So you want to make MongoDB aggregation on some collections. It's not supported by just creating Repository method with correct name. Spring Data Examples project has the sample how to do MongoDB aggregations:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/aggregation

There are more details about aggregation support in official documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation

Comment: I tried a code  but I don't get anything only countries , but airports no one , maybe that mongodb database return data faster than spring , I tried also to debug a code with log and subscribe to catch them but no one anymore !